# Disable Chrome extensions with Robot Framework's Open Browser method

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I need to open Chrome maximised with an experimental option to prevent a pop warning about extensions "disabled by your administrator".

Using Create WebDriver, I can get this working with

```
Open Chrome With Options
  ${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
  Call Method       ${options}    add_experimental_option      useAutomationExtension    ${FALSE}
  Call Method       ${options}    add_argument      start-maximized
  Create WebDriver  Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
  Go To             ${HOMEPAGE}
```

However, when I try something equivalent with Open Browser (see below), although the "useAutomationExtension" is working, the start-maximised setting is ignored.  Why is this?

```
Open Chrome with Capabilities
  ${args}=              Create List   start-maximised
  ${chrome_options}=    Create Dictionary
  ...    useAutomationExtension     ${FALSE}
  ...    args                       ${args}
  ${capabilities}=     Create Dictionary
  ...    chromeOptions    ${chrome_options}
  Open Browser  ${HOMEPAGE}  ${BROWSER}    desired_capabilities=${capabilities}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desired capabilities and chrome options are two different configurations. The keyword "Open Browser" doesn't support chrome options, so the only way to add options to chrome is by keywords "Create WebDriver"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all the params in the list. Then pass this list to Dictionary object and pass it to open a browser.

All the chrome options need to be passed as a dictionary object to Open Browser with key desired_capabilities.

Ex.

```
${options} =     Create List    --start-maximized    --disable-web-security <<any options that you need to add>>
${arguments} =     Create Dictionary    args=${options}
${capabilities} =     Create Dictionary    chromeOptions=${arguments}
Open Browser    https://www.google.com    remote_url=${grid_url}    browser=${BROWSER}    desired_capabilities=${capabilities}
```